# Specifying an unknown number of conditions

Tags: yara

Want to write a Yara rule that fires on a range of strings hitting. E.g.:

```
$rrr = "shell"

$var1 = "cheese"
$var2 = "beef"
$var3 = "chicken"

condition:

$rrr and ($var*) > 2
```

Can't seem to get anything like this to compile.

Tried the above, tried other various regexs and assorted nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear what you are going for with your sample above, but here are two options:

```
$rrr and (#var1+#var2+#var3) >= 2
```

- Will match on "shell cheese cheese"

--Or--

```
$rrr and (2 of ($var*))
```

- Will match on "shell cheese beef"
- But not "shell cheese cheese"